# Enable Bzip2 in php-fpm on Ubuntu

Tags: php, php-fpm, ubuntu-16.04

How can I enable functions like [bzopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bzopen.php) in php7.1-fpm on Ubuntu 16.04?

I'm using the packages from [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/bzip2.installation.php the package maintainer needs to compile this in.

Either

- convince your current provider to compile it in
- compile yourself
- find another package maintainer

Comment: Or switch distributions. For instance, Red Hat PHP builds include bzip2 functions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Or maybe just use the Ubuntu provided package. At least on 14.04 the Ubuntu provided php package supports `bzopen`.

Comment: I don't know about red hat, but Ubuntu official repositories doesn't have php7.1 at all (xenial is at 7.0, trusty still at 5.6, and not even at the latest releases... 7.0.15 instead of 7.0.20)

Answer (score 1):

You may not have installed the required php dependencies. Try installing php7.1-bz2 and php7.1-zip using:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-bz2 php7.1-zip
```